# Only return specific fields for specific groups when serializing with Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

Symfony 4. I have two entities, `Cat` and `Owner`.

```
class Cat
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups("cats")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups("cats")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Owner", mappedBy="cat")
     * @Groups("cats")
     */
    private $owners;
}

class Owner
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups("cats")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups("owners")
     */
    private $name;
}
```

My API endpoint needs to return 2 keys, `owners` (a list of all owners), and `cats` (a list of all cats, with their owners).

```
public function index()
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Owner::class);
    $owners = $repository->findAll();
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Cat::class);
    $cats = $repository->findAll();
    return $this->json([
        'owners' => $owners,
        'cats' => $cats,
    ], 200, [], ['groups' => ['owners', 'cats']]);
}
```

This works, but with 1 problem: the `cats` list contains the full owner information for each owner, i.e.:

```
{
  "owners": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John Smith"
    }
  ],
  "cats": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Miaow",
      "owners": [ 
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "John Smith"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want is for the `owners` key in the `cat` object to only return the owner's `id`, like this:

```
{
  "owners": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John Smith"
    }
  ],
  "cats": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Miaow",
      "owners": [ 
        1
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a getter for a specific group and with a specific serialized name.

In `Cat`:

```
/**
 * @Groups("cats")
 * @SerializedName("owners")
*/
public function getOwnersIds(): iterable
{
    return $this->getOwners()->map(function ($owner) {
        return $owner->getId();
    })->getValues();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Since `$this->getOwners()` returns a collection, not an array, it doesn't quite work. But you pointed me in the right direction. This works: `return $this->getOwners()->map(function ($owner) { return $owner->getId(); })->getValues();`. If you update your answer I'll mark it right.

Answer (score 0):

Override the mapping of a field.

See doctrine documentation:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html